# Extracting diagonal elements of a multidimensional array in Python to a single array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, arraylist

If I have a 3D array containing diagonal matrices of shape (3, 4, 4) like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[[1 , 0, 0, 0],
            [0 , 2, 0, 0],
            [0 , 0, 3, 0],
            [0 , 0, 0, 4]],

           [[5 , 0, 0, 0],
            [0 , 6, 0, 0],
            [0 , 0, 7, 0],
            [0 , 0, 0, 8]],

          [[9 , 0, 0, 0],
           [0 , 10, 0, 0],
           [0 , 0, 11, 0],
           [0 , 0, 0, 12]]])
```

How to extract the elements of each matrix like this:

```
B=np.array([[1 , 2, 3, 4],[5 , 6, 7, 8],[9 , 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: `np.diagonal(A, axis1=1, axis2=2)`?